# DoCmd.TransferText error 3051

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am attempting to import data into my MS Access project via TransferText, but am receiving error #3051: "The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ''.  It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permissions to view and write its data."

It is odd to me that the filename given in the error message is blank.  I have checked and rechecked the file name, even to perform a check "If Not fso.FileExists(file_name) Then ... End If" prior to the TransferText call.

I have also checked and rechecked the table name and the file permissions.  The table is successfully emptied before the TransferText call, so I know that works.  The file is in a subfolder relative to the Access database file in a folder on my desktop.  I have not set or unset any permissions for any of the folders or files.

Until now I had been using DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet to import the data that is downloaded from a web based tool, but I found Excel was misinterpreting some alphanumeric codes as numbers in scientific format, such as 1E100 would become 1E+100 in the Excel file, so the data was corrupted before getting to the Access database.  These codes are getting corrupted in uncorrectable ways, so I can't  modify the data after import.  I found I could save the data from the web tool as a CSV file rather than an Excel file; this led me to try to use DoCmd.TransferText.

Below is the code I am using:

```
Private Function ImportExcel( _
 ByVal file_name As String, _
 ByVal table_name As String _
) As Integer
    On Error GoTo Error

    Dim fso As FileSystemObject, folder_name As String

    Dim xl_book As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xl_sheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Dim i As Integer

' suppress excel's file-not-found popup
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    If Not fso.FileExists(file_name) Then
        ImportExcel = -1
        GoTo Finish
    End If

' gets a workbook from a global application object
    Set xl_book = Util.GetExcelWorkbook( _
        file_name:=file_name, _
        visible:=False, _
        use_cache:=True _
    )

    If xl_book Is Nothing Then
        ImportExcel = -1
        GoTo Finish
    End If

' always use the first worksheet
    Set xl_sheet = xl_book.Sheets(1)

' fake the first record to force columns types
    xl_sheet.range("A2").EntireRow.Insert
    For i = 1 To xl_sheet.UsedRange.columns.count
        xl_sheet.Cells(2, i) = "test"
    Next i

' make sure the table is closed
    DoCmd.Close _
        ObjectType:=acTable, _
        ObjectName:=table_name, _
        Save:=acSaveNo

' link to file
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    If ".csv" = Right(file_name, 4) Then
' empty table
        DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM " & table_name, True
' import data
        Debug.Print table_name
        Debug.Print file_name
        DoCmd.TransferText _
            TransferType:=acImportDelim, _
            SpecificationName:=table_name & " Import Spec", _
            TableName:=table_name, _
            FileName:=file_name, _
            HasFieldNames:=True
    Else
' delete table
        On Error Resume Next
        DoCmd.DeleteObject _
            ObjectType:=acTable, _
            ObjectName:=table_name
        If 0 <> Err.Number Then
            Resume Next
        End If
        On Error GoTo Error
' import data
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
            TransferType:=acImport, _
            TableName:=table_name, _
            FileName:=file_name, _
            HasFieldNames:=True, _
            range:=xl_sheet.NAME() & "!" & _
                xl_sheet.range( _
                    xl_sheet.Cells(1, 1), _
                    xl_sheet.Cells( _
                        xl_sheet.UsedRange.rows.count, _
                        xl_sheet.UsedRange.columns.count _
                    ) _
                ).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False), _
            SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9
    End If
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Finish:
    Set xl_sheet = Nothing
    If Not xl_book Is Nothing Then
        xl_book.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If
    Set xl_book = Nothing

    Set fso = Nothing

    Exit Function

Error:    
    Resume Finish
End Function
```

The two Debug.Print calls just prior to the DoCmd.TransferText call print exactly what is expected.

Comment: On a lark I tried importing the CSV via TransferSpreadsheet, and it mostly worked, except that the same data misinterpretation is occurring.  So I am really at a loss in regards to the 3051 error.

Comment: Is it possible to include your code in your question (between code tags)

Comment: Have you checked to see if the 'Read Only' attribute is set? Have you tried to move the file to the same folder as the database?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn yes to both, with no difference.  I have also put the file in C:\Temp\data.csv to rule out a too-long filepath issue (which I don't think it is).

Comment: Have you tried placing a breakpoint on the line that gets the error and looking at all your variables to make sure they are correct?  Can you post the code you are trying to run (including DIM's, etc.)?

Comment: Below is what I just tried (CSV, w/field names)... does your code look similar?
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "tablename", "C:\temp\0_Vista.csv", True

Comment: I've added my code to my original post.  I'm starting to think its not the code that's the problem, but perhaps system settings of some sort.

I looked again at the 'Read Only' attribute; it is not set for the file being imported, or any other file in the folder, however the folder its self has a blue square in the checkbox (not a checkmark, but a square which I think denotes some contained files are Read Only).  Unsetting the folder's Read Only attribute appears to work, but when I open the properties dialog for the folder again, the blue square has returned.

Comment: The reason for your error is because you have opened the Excel file, modified it (added 'test' to all of row 2), did NOT close it.

Comment: That was exactly it.  Only in this case it is not an excel file per se (.xls), but a .csv.  Moving the code that works with excel files out of the way of the code that works with csv files corrects the issue.  The reason I modify the Excel file is to attempt to force Excel/Access to read the data as text rather than a date or number or other format.

I suppose because I was feeding Excel a .csv, some conversion was occurring and the filename wasn't making it to the error message.

Comment: I agree it was a CSV, but you opened it in Excel, and since it was hidden you never realized it was opened in a modified state.